# Facing issue to create user for MongoDB Charts (On Prem)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, mongodb-charts

I'm facing an error when I create a user for MongoDB Charts through the CLI:

```
`add-user command error: clientAppId not found. No Charts apps configured to add user to.`
```

I followed the following setups specified on MongoDB docs for MongoDB Charts on-prem installation:

```
`https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/19.12/installation/`
```

The steps I followed are as follows:

1. Have a local MongoDB instance running.
2. Initialize Docker Swarm

   `docker swarm init`
3. Pull the chart image

   `docker pull quay.io/mongodb/charts:19.12.1`
4. Check connection through the internal CLI client

   `docker run --rm quay.io/mongodb/charts:19.12.1 charts-cli test-connection 'mongodb://host.docker.internal'`

Expected response:

```
`MongoDB connection URI successfully verified.`
```

5. Generate docker secret `charts-mongodb-uri`

   `echo "mongodb://host.docker.internal" | docker secret create charts-mongodb-uri -`
6. Deploy stack to swarm

   `docker stack deploy -c charts-docker-swarm-19.12.1.yml mongodb-charts`
7. Create User:

```
   $ docker exec -it \
   $(docker container ls --filter name=_charts -q) \
   charts-cli add-user --first-name "<First>" --last-name "<Last>" \
   --email "<user@example.com>" --password "<Password>" \
   --role "<UserAdmin|User>"
```

I'm getting back an error:

```
`add-user command error: clientAppId not found. No Charts apps configured to add user to.`
```

Docker Service Logs:

```
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ parsedArgs
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ installDir ('/mongodb-charts')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ log
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ salt
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ productNameAndVersion ({ productName: 'MongoDB Charts Frontend', version: '1.9.1' })
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ gitHash ('1a46f17f')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ supportWidgetAndMetrics ('on')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ tileServer (undefined)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ tileAttributionMessage (undefined)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ rawFeatureFlags (undefined)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchMigrationsLog ({ completedStitchMigrations: [] })
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ featureFlags ({})
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ lastAppJson ({})
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ existingInstallation (false)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ tenantId ('18c9543e-8677-4046-9166-5d54a2a6e1bb')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ chartsMongoDBUri
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ tokens
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ encryptionKeyPath
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchConfigTemplate
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ libMongoIsInPath (true)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ mongoDBReachable (true)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchMigrationsExecuted ([ 'stitch-1332',  'stitch-1897',  'stitch-2041',  'migrateStitchProductFlag',  'stitch-2041-local',  'stitch-2046-local',  'stitch-2055',  'multiregion',  'dropStitchLogLogIndexStarted' ])
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ minimumVersionRequirement (true)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchConfig
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchConfigWritten (true)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchChildProcess
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ indexesCreated (true)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchServerRunning (true)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ stitchAdminCreated (false)
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✔ lastKnownVersion ('0.9.0')
mongodb-charts_charts.1.ozvhqbhhmq9n@docker-desktop    |  ✖ existingClientAppIds failure: An error occurred authenticating: invalid username/password
```

Answer (score -1):

The “existingClientAppIds failure: An error occurred authenticating: invalid username/password” error seen in your logs can happen if the metadata database contains a previous installation of Charts, but the mongodb-charts_keys volume does not contain the required credentials. If you’re attempting a fresh installation, the easiest thing is to delete all data in the database and remove the Docker volume and start again.